# Is there a Semantic UI equivalent to Bootstrap's .container class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

Having used [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for some time and always wanting more in the way of admin UI features, I've decided to give [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) a try. The Semantic docs are a lot less concise than Bootstrap's, but each individual tool is fairly easy to implement. However, I've begun creating a basic UI to try out Semantic UI and I'm having trouble figuring out some of the basic stuff, like what to use as a suitable replacement for Bootstrap's `.container`, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Semantic UI author here. I will be adding a generic container class in next minor release.

Answer (score 1):

semantic-ui works differently while expecting about the grid system and the class `ui page grid` make the similar approach like bootstrap. You can see this example template too http://ehkoo.github.io/semantic-ui-examples/jumbotron where in the template you can change the classes to test. When class `ui grid` is applied, it takes the full-width and with `ui page grid` it works for 992px width with `padding-right` and `padding-left`. you can find the *media queries* for screen min-width 992px :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .ui.page.grid {
        padding: 0 8%;
    }
}
```

Besides, there is an issue you can follow. Link: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/175

And You can follow the documentation page: http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

I don't know if it's helpful for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do the following:

```
    <div class='ui centered grid'>
         <div class='fifteen wide column'>
          <!-- Below you can write your code -->
           <div class='ui menu'>
           <a class='active item'>Editorials</a>
           <a class='item'>Reviews</a>
           <a class='item'>Upcoming Events</a>
          </div>
         <!-- your code ends here -->
       </div>
    </div>
```